# How we i can check if one value from array A is Present in Array b then i will add in model class isSaved==true else isSaved==false

Tags: android, arrays, android-studio, sorting, arraylist

I have two files first statusFiles in which i get all what's  app status and savedFiles in which i getting files from specific folder which i stored through this status saver i am storing the path, Name, isSaved in model class one by one of each element of the status files if element is already present in savedFles then isSaved==true else isSaved==false

here is code which i am using

```
val statusFiles: Array<File>?
        val savedFiles = allFiles.execute()
        statusFiles = wAFolder.listFiles()
        imageList.clear()
        if (statusFiles != null && statusFiles.size > 0) {
            Arrays.sort(statusFiles)
            for (file in statusFiles) {
               for (i in savedFiles){
               if (file.name.contains(i.name)){
                   statusModel = StoryModel(file, file.name, file.absolutePath,true)
               }else{
                   statusModel = StoryModel(file, file.name, file.absolutePath,false)
               }
               }
                if (!statusModel.isVideo && statusModel.title.endsWith(".jpg")) {
                    imageList.add(statusModel)
                    

                }

            }
```

Comment: What is your question? Also, please reformat your code to make it more readable.

Comment: I have an array list in which I am getting all files that users saved from status saver then in other array list i am getting all latest seen whats app status .my task is during aading each file element in model class check if it is already saved the isSaved =true a variable in model class if not saved the isSaved=false